# Override parent theme deregister

Tags: jquery, child-theme, wp-enqueue-script, parent-theme

I have a parent theme that deregisters a script, in my case jquery. It does it like this:

```
function parent_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

    [...]
}
```

However, in my child theme I want to use jquery in order for some plugins to work properly. I cannot simply name it `jquery2`, because plugins always seem to look for `jquery` spelled exactly like that.

I don't want to override the parent function, because it also does a whole bunch of other stuff in that function, that could potentially be updated in the future.

**So how do I "reregister" jquery, even though the parent theme deregisters it?**

Comment: You can hook to `wp_enqueue_scripts` with a lower priority (i.e. a greater number). E.g. `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_function', 99 )` - here, the priority is `99`..

Comment: Thank you, that actually solved my problem!